# Override ProcessCmdKey C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code that overrides the TextBox ProcessCmdKey method:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case: //something to do etc etc.
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I use the above code, I can't write in the TextBox. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you've handled everything, pass it on to the base control:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case /* whatever */:
        // ...
        default:
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's better than my answer, we should always call the `base`'s method by default in an `override`.

Answer (score 0):

If you return `true` it means the input was processed and it won't be pass to the next control, return `false` and it should work as you expect.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)